# How to get ipv6 if ipv4 does not exist in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, ip-address

I know how to get ipv4 and ipv6 but I have problem.
My task is to write the code that will get the ipv4 if it exists if not get ipv6

My source for get ipv4 looks:

```
szIPAdress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
'szIPAdress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(szIPAdress).AddressList.ToString()
Dim hostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(szIPAdress)
Dim ip As IPAddress() = hostname.AddressList
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd want to do it the other way around: get the IPv6 address if it exists. If it doesn't, then fall back to IPv4. You want to use IPv6 if at all possible. Anyway, what goes wrong with the code you currently have? Perhaps consider `Dns.GetHostAddresses`.

Comment: I have a computer without addres IPv6, when I try to get ipv6 that computer return a value equals to 1, so i don't know how to check in code when IPv6 exists - thats my main problem

Comment: Use the `AddressFamily` property of the `IPAddress` object. Returns either `InterNetwork` for IPv4 or `InterNetworkV6` for IPv6.

Comment: @Elgahir an IPv6 address of "1" is probably "::1" which is the loopback address. Similar purpose as 127.0.0.1 on IPv4.

Comment: @CodyGray so that should works
   szIPAdress =        System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(szIPAdress).AddressList(0).ToString

            If (szIPAdress = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)


But that does not work

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these which should help you:

Use this to get **IPv4**:

```
Public Function GetIPv4Address() As String

    Dim hostEntry As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())

    Dim address As String = ""

    Try
        address = hostEntry.AddressList().Where(Function(a) a.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First().ToString()
    Catch
    End Try

    Return address

End Function
```

Use this to get **IPv6**:

```
Public Function GetIPv6Address() As String

    Dim hostEntry As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())

    Dim address As String = ""

    Try
        address = hostEntry.AddressList().Where(Function(a) a.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6).First().ToString()
    Catch
    End Try

    Return address

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't have problem to get a adres but I have problem to determine if addres IPv6 exists.

At my computer I have only addres IPv4 so I don't know when return IPv4 or IPv6  i tried to used that if  If (szIPAdress = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6) 

But that does not work.

Comment: @Elgahir If you call GetIPv6Address and it returns "" it will mean that address doesn't exist. The catch will handle that.

Comment: in my case program return ::01 so i think that's the problem. I don't know if that is a standard or not

Comment: if you have more propose or tips that would be great

Comment: ::01 is the loopback address so probably not what you're after. You could do a check for this I guess? You're probably looking for something like this 2340:0023:AABA:0A01:0055:5054:9ABC:ABB0 as an example. Have a look at [this](http://ipv6.com/articles/general/IPv6-Addressing.htm) to help understand it a little more.

Comment: Yeah could do. It's basically local host so unless you want that you could check for it and exclude it. I would use OrElse though.